# Permanent immobilization in League of Legends by 2 champions

Tags: league-of-legends

With the introduction of new masteries in Season 6, 45% cooldown is now a thing, and as a guy that likes to have fun in this game I wanted to know if it is possible to **immobilize** a single enemy champion **permanently** (as long as they dont use an item like Quicksilver Sash or Cleanse, and as mana lasts). If there is not, is there anything close to this?

Take into consideration that I say **immobilize** and not **stun** because it opens up the possibilities to spells like Morgana's binding and Maokai's W. I just dont want it to **move**. Ah, and it needs to be done with **2 champions** (For bot lane cheese purposes of course...)

EDIT: It can be any type of **chained CC that prevents the enemy from moving at will** (charms, snares, fears, stuns, knockups, etc...).

Comment: So you don't want stuns, just snares and knockups?

Comment: @Magmagod It can be stuns. I only said Immobilize to allow snares and knockups to be included as well. Fears can also be included. Any sort of CC that prevents you from moving at will.

Comment: I will get back to this question later when i can actually Fact Check my assumptions, if it isn't already responded by then, don't have access to the entire info right now

Comment: Given poppy's current state, she can do a 6-second cc-lock without another champion at all

Comment: @BenCraig Seems interesting. How so?

Comment: Apparently its only 5 now because her ult got nerfed (my bad). But it was e stun, snapcast ult, e stun again

Comment: the stun only happens against a wall no? @BenCraig

Answer (score 8):

There is only one way to do so, and there might be a small window where the guy can actually move, but these are the optimized CC and best situation :

**Rammus + morgana.**

Taunt at lvl 5 is 2.25s cc, with 12 s cooldown without cdr, that goes at 6.4 s at 45% reduction. his powerball knocks for like 1s for a 10 s cd, reduced at 5.5s with 45%

There comes morgana, 3second root with a 11s cd, reduced at 6.05 seconds  with 45% cd.

So all cc added in a perfectly timed rotation you have 2.25 + 3 + 1 , so 6.25 second crowd control.

it gives you enough time to refresh cooldowns and start the rotation again, and you even got morgana's ult to make it safer.

ALERT : it will never happen in game. This theory is based on 45% cdr for both players, beeing at least lvl  13, and the opponent having 0 tenacity, and not dying all that time. your synchro also has to be more than perfect.

DISCLAIMER : these are theorical numbers and these should work like that. Unfortunately, some spells are capped and can't go under a certain CD. I'm not sure if these spells are concerned, but it might be the case. Giving it a try is the best way to know if it will work.

Comment: Please also give attention to Magmagod answer, the comments can answer some question you might want to ask !

Comment: "Instant" actions aren't actually instant. Morgana Q has a cast time of about 0.25s just like Rammus E and Q (note i m not refering to projectile travel-time). An ability's cd starts after the cast ends, therefor the enemy has about 0.5s to react between ccs. That means he can easily flash or use an escape ability. Therefor **there is no way to do so**. Check casting times here: leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Channel.

Comment: Also Rammus Q knocks up for about 0.75 seconds.

Comment: yeh, but about cast time, it means you have to cast it 0.25s before the taunt ends, so the cage hits on the end of the taunt etc, but as I said it is almost impossible to realize manually and will never happen in game.

Comment: "..you have to cast it 0.25s before the taunt ends" - True, but this means that if the cc lasts for a total of 6s then you would have to cast it after 5.75s, meaning you have less time available than most people (that assume 0 cast time) would think. If you draw it on paper you ll see what I mean (it's hard to visualize without doing so).

Answer (score 2):

From what i remember of my game knowledge, one of the best most Everlasting CC chains can either be a **Rammus + Fiddle** ,because their taunt and fear last between 2.25 to 2.75 seconds if i'm not mistaken, or **Fiddle + Morgana**, i think these combos would mainly depend on the base cooldown of the skills since you are going for 45% CDR

I will provide actual numbers later at night, for now this is the best i can do, feel free to make any edit if you know the values or if i got it wrong at some point

Comment: a bit too late mate, and rammus morg is better since rammus got the powerball :)

Comment: ahah yeah i saw your's literally go up a bit after mine, just wondering, isn't leona a good one to consider? Since she can alone lock you don't for 4 seconds or such

Comment: leona e + q combo last actually less time than rammus (it lasts 1.75s), and her ult can not really be considered in the equation since the cooldown is too long for an infinite roation

Comment: Can you check something to consider? How long is renekton stun and what is the base cooldown? I'm assuming it lasts at least 2.10 or smth seconds, but the CD is also a factor to consider since he wants an infinite rotation

Comment: Red renekton stuns for 1.5s on w and cd is 9s, so it is less optimized than rammus

Comment: Very well my friend, thanks for checking for me, have a nice day and good luck on the Rift out there (Careful with that Shaco behind you!)

Comment: You're very welcome, don't hesitate to double check or try some other combos, I would be glad to discover something better than these two, I may have forgotten one char or two! Good luck have fun on the rift!

Answer (score 1):

First off, please enjoy this chart that I found: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7C6rhO0KHRIs1SBBLPvuTVbsFmuTtR3zB99XMMJ8yU/edit#gid=140485586

**Thresh/Caitlyn** - Thresh's hook, at lvl 5 with 45% cdr, assuming you hit the one before, has a 3.6 second cooldown and lasts for 1.5 seconds. Caitlyn's traps take 1.1 seconds to activate, so with proper placement you can easily snare immediately after thresh hook ends. That snare  lasts 2 seconds. With a thresh flay in between to fill up the .1 second gap (and possibly caitlyn e for slow, or more traps surrounding for minimal escape routes), you can then hook again and repeat. The only real delay will be timing his flay, and the delay in his hook cast. However, if caitlyn traps again right in front/behind, thresh's flay can knock them into that trap for another 2 seconds. Caityln's traps, even without cdr, will be up often enough for more repeats than you will need.

**Thresh/Blitzcrank** - Another fun one, that I'm sure you've tried if you enjoy messing around, is blitz + thresh. Thresh hook, then blitz hook, followed by immediate knock up, followed by thresh flay, followed by another thresh hook. Missing .6 seconds if you don't include flay. The great thing though is blitz R for silence so they can't flash or dash out during the .6 seconds, and thresh's flay will have a brief pull and a slow so they definitely will not get away especially without flashes/dashes. This one is especially fun because of the unexpected damage of those abilities + blitz passive goes off for free and thresh's e passive makes the 1 auto he can get off very potent. Not infinite, but a very very painful 3 seconds with no counterplay, and a very strong possibility between the slow and silence for at least one repeat if needed. If you're bot lane as you mentioned, that damage should be enough for many supports and all adc's.

**Fiddlesticks/Maokai** - Fiddlesticks is a fun one to do this with as well, try fiddlesticks and maokai. The fids E silence can be used to fill the brief gap (not quite infinite cc, but very close and a slow/silence will fill the gap) so they can't dash or flash away. Fids Q, Maokai W, maokai Q + fids E, Maokai E for more slows + damage. The problem with this one is the mana dependency. 2 second root every 4.95 seconds. 2.25 second fear every 6.05 seconds. Also very solid if lead with Maokai W, then Fids Q, then the rest again. Shorter gap between abilities for the first repeat.

**Alistar/Nautilus** - This I believe (I'd have to double check numbers) is permanent, but difficult due to alistar headbutt/q combo and nautilus long cast times and the pull of his q.

**Leona/Morgana** - Leona E: roots as travel, so basically just land it for free q. It supposedly lasts about .5 seconds. Q 1.25 second stun every 3.85. Morgana q: 3 seconds every 6.05. This means Q for 1.25 seconds on Leona, Q for morg for another 3, Q again on Leona for another 1.25 seconds, and you're missing 1.8 seconds in between. While this isn't an infinite rotation, you can get this rotation three times between Leona's E+R for one gap, and Morgana's R + leona E for the 2nd gap. Then another leona E after the 3rd gap, means a total of: 5.5*3 + 2(1.8 needed but both fills are 2)*2 + .5, 21 seconds of CC. Leona's E is up every 4.05 seconds so used as a filler between 5.5 seconds of CC shouldn't be a problem.

**Morgana/Sion** - Sion, 2 second channel of Q for 2.25 second knock up, goes on CD for 3.3 seconds after use, so need 3.05 seconds of CC before next usage goes off. He can also ult in between if need be, so can Morgana. Morgana I think works best, though leaves .05 seconds of escape potential, plus need VERY good timing. Hard slow on sion e helps during that time as well.

**Poppy + Tahm Kench** - Lets not forgot the trolliest of them all, Tahm Kench. Tahm Kench + Poppy is an absolutely godly combination. The hard part is how to get Tahm Kench passive stacks up. You can do this with a q slow of his, or a poppy stun if they get near terrain / on the wrong side of poppy to be pushed to tahm. Tahm q stun for 1.5 seconds once his passive is stacked, followed by swallow for 3 seconds, where he is able to put them exactly where poppy needs to ram them into terrain again for another 2 second stun every 5.5 seconds. Get his stacks up again (as swallow destroys them) and he can stun again for 1.5 seconds, every 3.3 seconds, then eat them and repeat. A slight variation is to start with tahm stun, don't eat them, and then have poppy stun if they're already near a wall. This allows for two of tahm's 1.5s stuns, with 1 of poppy's 2 second stun, for a total of 5 seconds, then eat them to fill the gap, and poppy will be able to stun again, followed by tahm, for a total CC time of: 11.5 seconds. Since Tahm's swallow is a 5.5 second cd, and there's another 3.5 seconds of stun afterward his first devour, it's not an infinite chain, but it is 11.5 seconds with only a 1.8 second gap between a repeat.

These are just some combo's that I think work well, try and mix and match as well. I know you asked for permanent CC, which is very difficult, but going along with your theme these combo's can either get you very close (or in some cases with perfect timing, on the nose), or be devastating damage wise with a ton of CC, and tons of fun to do.

In this vein as well, though not the same, is **Trundle/Anivia**. New anivia allows for much easier stuns to land, and you can block off the entire lane, and if done right, displace them in the process. They also have slows and plenty of damage.